# Rails 7 with Tailwind build or precompile automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a Rails 7.0.4 app with Tailwind.
When I use a css tailwind class for the first time in the project, I need to run `rails assets:precompile` then run again `./bin/dev` to see the result.

Is there a way to make rails precompile assets each time I save my file?

Comment: I just recently created a Rails v7 template with Tailwind integrated and also this "livereload" functionality. Maybe you can take a look to check differences with your app: https://github.com/ralixjs/rails-ralix-tailwind. Hope it helps!

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Answer (score 0):

In following the [Tailwind on Rails Guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails), your `Procfile.dev` will be updated such that this happens. You have not provided details on your Procfile which makes this difficult to diagnose but I anticipate that it’s missing the line `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch`.

This line allows you to watch for changes and recompiles when they happen.

Comment: I set the same configuration and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have this set in my Procfile and still need to precompile to load Tailwind CSS classes when I use them for the first time.

Comment: On Rails 7.0.8, I have the `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch` line in my `Procfile.dev` and I too often seem to need to stop server, precompile and start server again.